# How to redirect with a variable path segment?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I spent some minutes to try to resolve this but I can't.

I would like to make a redirection rule that redirects:

```
https://www.example.com/membres/XXX/participations/
```

To:

```
https://www.example.com
```

Whatever the value of `XXX` as long as the URL has the same pattern (begins with "membres" and finish with "participations").

This is the code I wrote before but it did not work, please explain to me what's wrong:

```
RewriteRule ^membres/(.*)/participations/$ /
```

Comment: this is server side. I don't want regex but just a simple way to do that.

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^membres/.*/participations/?$ /`

Comment: that's work ! thanks. This is the code i wrote before but it did not work, please explain me whats is wrong : `RewriteRule ^membres/(.*)/participations/$ /`

Comment: your code : `RewriteRule ^membres/.*/participations/?$ /`
my code   : `RewriteRule ^membres/(.*)/participations/$ /`
there is two differences : `(.*)` and `?`. Does it matter ?

Comment: Besides the capturing group that you don't need, only difference is the `?`. Capturing group (the parenthesis part) allows to use whatever it matches as a variable. The `?` makes the previous character or group optional, the slash in this case

Comment: ok that's ok, thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^membres/(.*)/participations/$ /
> ```

Assuming this directive is near the top of you config file and providing you also included an `R` (`redirect`) flag to trigger an external redirect, and possibly included the `L` (`last`) to prevent later directives (if any) from rewriting the URL then this directive should have redirected the example URL given in your question.

If you omit the `R` flag then it will trigger an *internal rewrite*. No external redirect will occur.

The only real difference with the directive suggested in comments, is that it makes the trailing slash optional. So, if that enabled the redirection to work then it would imply that the requested URL did not contain a trailing slash.

The capturing backreference (ie. `(.*)`) is not required. And you should consider making this pattern more restrictive to only match a single path segment, rather than *anything*?

If you have no other mod_rewrite directives in your `.htaccess` then you should consider using a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive instead, which is arguably more efficient:

```
RedirectMatch ^/membres/.*/participations/?$ /
```